# Getting index of the current element in Python list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list: 
`new_list = [1,2,3,7,9,5]`

I want to find a function/solution if I have to find the index of the element when I am iterating over the list and the value is 1.
For eg-

```
Sum = 0
for i in new_list:
  if i == 1:
    Sum += <position of this 1>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate()`

```
new_list = [1,2,3,7,9,5]
index_you_want = 'doesnt exist'
for i, value in enumerate(new_list):
    print (i, value)
    if value == 1:
        index_you_want = i
print (index_you_want)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get index of an element with `index()` method:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 5]
ind = new_list.index(1)
print(ind)
```

If your element repeated in list, get a list of indexes this way:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 9, 5]
ind = [i for i, a in enumerate(new_list) if a == 1]
print(ind)
```